# Make div the height of viewport

Tags: html, css, height, viewport

I am designing a website and I would like the top to be the height of the viewport like this
[website](https://yourkarma.com/).

How do I do something like that?

The bottom is always sitting on the bottom of my screen no matter what monitor I use?

Thanks

Comment: On page you mentioned as example the height of first `header` updated via JS after page is loaded

Answer (score 45):

I know it's an old question, but you can also use vh (viewport height) units. It's supported by all modern <strike>desktop</strike> browsers, <strike>on mobile devices it may create some issues so work around it using media queries</strike>.

```
div {height:100vh;}
```

Meaning 100% of viewport height.

[Here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#lengths) is a W3C draft specifying relative length units, and before you use any of them check Internet Explorer support as it doesn't support every single unit.

Answer (score 7):

You can set a divider to be the same height as the window by setting:

```
html, body { height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
div { height:100%; }
```

This question gets asked a lot here, it's best to search first. :-)